# How to specify a default culture for Service Fabric applications?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, culture, service-fabric-stateless

Is there a way to declare a default culture for Service Fabric stateless/statefull services as it is for web applications? In a web application, I used the following declaration:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

But for Service Fabric applications, I have to include the following code in service initialization:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in Program.cs

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

Optionally, you can get the culture name from a [configuration setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-how-to-parameterize-configuration-files).

`<Section Name="MyConfigSection">
   <Parameter Name="Culture" Value="en-US" />
</Section>`

and read it from code:

```
var configurationPkg = Context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");
var cultureName= configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["MyConfigSection"].Parameters["Culture"];
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureName);
```